# Is SSH unstable in AdvancedTomato?

Tags: ssh, tomato

I'm able to login to my AdvancedTomato router via SSH to update config files. But eventually I find that SSH no longer works. Is SSH in Tomato unstable to the point that it eventually gets hung if you use it too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answering my own question that was making me question Tomato this week!)

It's stable! Turns out there's a default option under `Administration->Admin Access->Admin Restrictions` called `Limit Connection Attempts` that defaults to 3 SSH connection attempts per minute. This limit does *not* reset with a successful connection. So rapid connections/disconnections (say if using SCP to transfer a file, then SSH to login) will cause this to kick in.

In that case, wait 60 seconds and it will come back.